# install v8js extension to php

Tags: python, v8

I'm trying to install v8js on a local http/ssh server built with Debian 9.3, so I need to install v8 chromium engine first according to this [documentation](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/README.Linux.md).

But when I'm trying to run the command line `tools/dev/v8gen.py -vv x64.release -- is_component_build=true` the command sends me this:

```
################################################################################
/usr/bin/python -u tools/mb/mb.py gen -f infra/mb/mb_config.pyl -m developer_default -b x64.release out.gn/x64.release

  Writing """\
  is_debug = false
  target_cpu = "x64"
  """ to /home/dev/v8/out.gn/x64.release/args.gn.

  /home/dev/v8/buildtools/linux64/gn gen out.gn/x64.release --check
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tools/mb/mb.py", line 67, in Main
      ret = self.args.func()
    File "tools/mb/mb.py", line 317, in CmdGen
      return self.RunGNGen(vals)
    File "tools/mb/mb.py", line 856, in RunGNGen
      ret, _, _ = self.Run(cmd)
    File "tools/mb/mb.py", line 1378, in Run
      ret, out, err = self.Call(cmd, env=env, buffer_output=buffer_output)
    File "tools/mb/mb.py", line 1392, in Call
      env=env)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
      errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 304, in <module>
    sys.exit(gen.main())
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 298, in main
    return self._options.func()
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 166, in cmd_gen
    gn_outdir,
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 208, in _call_cmd
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-u', 'tools/mb/mb.py', 'gen', '-f', 'infra/mb/mb_config.pyl', '-m', 'developer_default', '-b', 'x64.release', 'out.gn/x64.release']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Obviously I can not continue the following installation steps (I can't use ninja) and I do not really know about Python so a help would be really convenient :)

PS: I saw (I don't remember where) that there is probably minimum RAM (8GB) and Disk space (100GB) requirements to build v8, is that it ...?

Comment: What kind of machine are you doing this on? The instructions assume x86_64. "Exec format error" sounds like maybe you're trying this on a 32-bit machine? Or an ARM box (like RasPi)? -- Other hardware requirements are much lower than what you quote; 1GB RAM and 5GB disk should be enough.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah I'm on debian 32-bit, this is the issue then, thanks. So there is no way to install it on a 32-bit machine ? :/

Comment: It should be possible, but I don't know how. Since it apparently doesn't work out of the box, it might be a bit of work. For the issue you're running into, you'll need a 32-bit build of `gn`: either find a download source, or compile it yourself. There might be additional issues afterwards, as this setup is apparently untested -- not many 32-bit machines around these days...

Comment: Okay then, upgrade my machine to 64-bit would be the easiest solution I guess, thanks for the tips though, really helpful!